# Any downside to feeding a buck regulator into a linear one?

Tags: power-supply, buck, linear-regulator

I need to convert 12 V down to 5 V and 3.3 V.

I am using linear regulators right now but they get pretty warm and eventually I would like to supply more current for it (around 500-700 mA).

If I used a buck converter to get the voltage down to 5 V, then also feed the 5 V into the 3.3 V linear regulator is that acceptable? Assuming the buck converter can handle the current of the 5 V components *and* the 3.3 V ones? Also, this would cut down on heat from the linear regulator, correct?

Answer (score 1):

The only drawback is loss of efficiency if any. Depends on how efficient a 12 to 3.3V linear regulator would be or a 5v to 3.3v switching regulator would be. Otherwise, a linear regulator typically tends to smooth and is less noisy than a switching reg, and has less complicated layout requirements. Everything is a trade off, but 5V to 3.3V is often done with ldo instead of switching regs for noise abatement reasons

Comment: Ok thanks , just wanted to make sure there wasn't something where the two don't mix. I'm fine with an efficiency loss

Comment: They compliment each other. It's all a cost benefit analysis.

Comment: @Tom you could also go with a tighter compromise if you wish to have the benefit of both worlds, buck down to 3.5V and chop off .2V (and all of the ripple) with the LDO.

Answer (score 0):

The downside is power losses .The linear will waste some power .When you go from 5 to 3V3 you can expect the linear reg to be 66% efficient .If your buck converter is 90% efficient your overall efficiency would be about 60% .This downside is relevant at high power.